# why these cookie codes didn't work in asp.net mvc?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, cookies, asp.net-mvc-5, shopping-cart

I'm developing an `asp.net mvc 5` online store project . I want to create `cart` to add Goods with `Cookie` . I'm confused about it and don't know why it didn't work . it didn't gave me any error . also I add break points to debug it but any data didn't send to my actions ! 
could anyone help me ? what's the problem ? 
I'm not good in `javascript` and I think problem would be in javascript codes :/ 
Thanks in advance

**Goods controller**

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult AddToCart(int Id, int Count)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Request.Cookies.AllKeys.Contains("NishtmanCart_" + Id.ToString()))
            {
                //edit cookie 
                var cookie = new HttpCookie("NishtmanCart_" + Id.ToString(), (Convert.ToInt32(Request.Cookies["NishtmanCart_" + Id.ToString()].Value) + 1).ToString());
                cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1);
                cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                Response.Cookies.Set(cookie);
            }
            else
            {
                //add new cookie
                var cookie = new HttpCookie("NishtmanCart_" + Id.ToString(), Count.ToString());
                cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1);
                cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
            }
            int CartCount = Request.Cookies.AllKeys.Where(p => p.StartsWith("NishtmanCart_")).Count();
            return Json(new MyJsonData()
            {
                Success = true,
                Script = MessageBox.Show("product added to your basket", MessageType.Success).Script,
                Html = "Shopping Cart (" + CartCount.ToString() + ")"
            });
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return Json(new MyJsonData()
            {
                Success = false,
                Script = MessageBox.Show("product didn't add to your basket", MessageType.Error).Script,
                Html = ""
            });
        }
    }

    public ActionResult RemoveCart(int Id)
    {

        try
        {
            int CartCount = Request.Cookies.AllKeys.Where(p => p.StartsWith("NishtmanCart_")).Count();

            if (Request.Cookies.AllKeys.Contains("NishtmanCart_" + Id.ToString()))
            {
                Request.Cookies["NishtmanCart_" + Id.ToString()].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
                return Json(new MyJsonData()
                {
                    Success = true,
                    Script = MessageBox.Show("product removed from your basket", MessageType.Success).Script,
                    Html = "Shopping Cart (" + CartCount.ToString() + ")"
                });
            }
            else
            {
                return Json(new MyJsonData()
                {
                    Success = false,
                    Script = MessageBox.Show("this product doesn't have in your basket", MessageType.Warning).Script,
                    Html = "Shopping Cart (" + CartCount.ToString() + ")"
                });
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return Json(new MyJsonData()
            {
                Success = true,
                Script = MessageBox.Show("product didn't remove from your basket", MessageType.Error).Script,
                Html = ""
            });
        }

    }
```

**MyJsonData.cs**

```
public class MyJsonData
{
    public string Script { get; set; }
    public string Html { get; set; }
    public bool Success { get; set; }
}
```

**_GoodDetailsAjax.cshtml**

```
 @foreach (var item in Model.GoodDetails)
{
  <div>
       <p class="nowprice">NowPrice : @item.DetailsNowPrice</p>
       <p class="preprice">PrePrice : @item.DetailsPrePrice</p>
        <a class="button icon-cart" href="#" GoodID="@item.DetailsGoodID">Add to cart</a><br>
        <a class="link" >Shopping Cart (0)</a>
    </div>
}
 @section scripts{
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("a.button.icon-cart").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var goodId = $(this).attr("GoodID");
            alert(goodId); //////// I just added this code
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Goods/AddToCart",
                data: { Id: goodId, Count: 1 },
                type: "Post",
                dataType: "Json",
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result.Success) {
                        $("#CartItems").html(result.Html);
                    }
                    eval(result.Script);
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Error!");
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
 }
```

Comment: what problem are you facing with this code ? can you please be more specific ?

Comment: You're returning JSON, which I assume means you're making AJAX requests. If you want to add/remove cookies, you need to make HTTP requests.

Comment: It didn't work , when I click on 'Add to cart button ' it should be added 1 count to `Shopping cart ` a tag , but it didn't @FrebinFrancis

Comment: Yes but I used Ajax for another issue not for this @TiesonT.

Comment: The controller code shown returns JSON, not HTML, so how are you using it, if not via an XMLHttpRequest?

Comment: I don't know :/ @TiesonT. I thought JSON and Ajax are the same type . I'm new in it  . what changes need to fix it ? :/

Comment: @shima amini What is the Type of that AddToCart action ? POST or GET ?

Comment: I don't think so , I do all converts @FrebinFrancis

Comment: @shima amini are you getting any breakpoint hit on AddToCart action ? when you debugging

Comment: I don't use any of them `GET` and `POST ` :| . All of my codes are in my post dear @FrebinFrancis , Yes I do debugging , I don't see any data in action parameters ! (sorry for my bad English ...)

Comment: [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) is not [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) (or vice versa), nor is AJAX a "type" - it's a term used to describe a variety of methods for requesting additional resources without refreshing the parent page.

Comment: @shima amini By default all actions in controller is of TYPE "GET" but you did a POST request call to that method "AddToCart"

Comment: I added `HttpPost` attribute to `AddToCart` action but it didn't work yet @FrebinFrancis

Comment: @shima amini Are you sure you are getting value for goodId in Ajax Call ?

Comment: No I'm not sure :( did you mean this ? `var goodId = $(this).attr("GoodID");` @FrebinFrancis

Comment: @shima amini yes exactly please give an alert before  $.ajax({ like alert(goodId);

Comment: Thank you dear @TiesonT. so what changes I need ? I'm confused about that , because I used  json and javascript and ... all together and I'm ....

Comment: To use your existing code? Either use a [client-side library for manipulating cookies](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie), or use an iframe as your POST target, and return a regular response in that iframe; modifying cookies in that frame has the effect of modifying the same cookies in the parent page.

Comment: Sorry , did you mean like this ? https://jsfiddle.net/pennukw6/ @FrebinFrancis

Comment: @shima amini yes exactly. in that alert you just try to show the goodId variable and see the value is there in the variable.

Comment: you're right , thank you . But sorry  I don't understand what I should doing ? @FrebinFrancis

Comment: @shima amini you got the correct value in alert box?

Comment: No , I didn't get any alert @FrebinFrancis

Comment: @shima amini can you please update your question with current code so i can check that

Comment: I updated my post , but I just added `[HttpPost]` to action and an `alert` to scripts :/ @FrebinFrancis

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100549/discussion-between-frebin-francis-and-shima-amini).

Comment: I solved it @FrebinFrancis :) I posted my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of my codes was true , I just made some simple mistakes .

I loaded a JQuery file in my layout and also I loaded another version of JQuery in my view! I deleted one of them .

And also I used those codes in a partial view and loaded they using Ajax but  my partial view couldn't pass data to Controller  , I moved codes to main view (`GoodDetails.cshtml`)  and it works fine now .

Comment: With your helps ...Thank you dear @FrebinFrancis :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what's the implementation of `MessageBox.Show("....", MessageType.Error).Script` but I'm assuming that it just generates a simple JavaScript statement like this:

```
Script = "alert('product added to your basket');"
```

So you can add this tag for the result:

```
<div id="CartItems">

</div>
```

Now it works without any problem.